# State update causes another render even if using primitive value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I am using the last version of Expo (47.0.8) in my react native project.
React version is : 18.1.0

Edit : I produce that even in a bare React Native project without Expo. (react 18)

No strict mode enabled.

It seems that updating a state with the same value cause another render, only once.
Even if the value is a primitive, like a number ( not an object )

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

  function updateValue() {
    setValue(11);
  }

  console.log("RENDER !", value);
  
  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop:200}} onPress={updateValue}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>Update value</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>{value}</Text>
    </>
  );
}
```

So when the app start the output :

> RENDER! 10

First click on the TouchableOpacity :

> RENDER! 11

Second click on the TouchableOpacity :

> RENDER! 11

Then, other clicks don't display anything.

Snack example (**check only on mobile** it does not happen on expo web) :

https://snack.expo.dev/yalexm1mw?platform=ios

Comment: setColor? setValue, maybe?

Comment: Not just a typo in my question. I have updated it.